# Multiple Select using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have LINQ query like this

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

IEnumerable<InvitationMails> customers = context.InvitationMails
            .Where(c => c.LinkStart == null)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(c => {
                c.LinkStart = start;
                return c;
            });
```

I need to select `LinkStart`, `LinkEnd`, and `Link` columns with checking for null values like this.

```
.Where(c => c.LinkStart == null)
.Where(c => c.LinkEnd == null)
.Where(c => c.Link == null)
```

But how do write query for select?

Model

```
public string Link { get; set; }
public DateTime? LinkStart { get; set; }
public DateTime? LinkEnd { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are `LinkStart`, `LinkEnd`, and `Link` of the same Type?

Comment: Link start and LinkEnd yes. Link not

Comment: Could you give me the types?

Comment: Instead of creating a struct for your selections, you can simply select as an anonymous object. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the properties you are trying to select aren't all of the same type, you need to create a `struct` if you want to keep them all in the same `IEnumerable`. An `IEnumerable<pair<string, pair<DateTime?, DateTime?>>>` would also work, but the struct solution seems cleaner.

```
public struct Customer
{
   string Link;
   DateTime? LinkStart;
   DateTime? LinkEnd;

   public Customer(string link, DateTime? linkStart, DateTime? linkEnd)
   {
       this.Link = link
       this.LinkStart = linkStart;
       this.LinkEnd = linkEnd;
   }
}
```

Once you have that then you can do:

```
        .Where(c => c.LinkStart == null)
        .Where(c => c.LinkEnd == null)
        .Where(c => c.Link == null)
        .Select(c => new Customer(c.Link, c.LinkStart, c.LinkEnd));
```

Comment: You can replace your three `where` statements with `&&` operator!

Comment: Sure, but that isn't what OP asked for.

Comment: BTW it would be better if you suggest to use `&&` instead of multiple where.

Comment: Why not just use anonymous objects? If the OP happens to selection another combination of columns, must they create another struct for that? Wouldn't that be very clumsy?

Answer (score 4):

LINQ allows you to select any combination of properties you want *without* having to define a type for every combination of properties. When you don't specify type in your `Select`, your selections are *morphed* into an anonymous object. This is how you can do it:

```
var result = context.InvitationMails
             .Where(c => c.LinkStart == null && c.LinkEnd == null && c.Link == null)
             .Select(c => new { c.LinkStart, c.LinkEnd, c.Link });
```

`result` is an anonymous object with the properties specified.

Note that, as long as you are not required to pass the `result` object to any method, or return `result` from the current method, you are good to go. However, if you do need to do any of that, you have to create a class (or struct) for that (or, you could make do with `object` at the expense of type inference/intellisense).

Also note that you don't have to chain the `Where` one after another, you can simply use boolean operators like `&&` to separate your conditions.

**Edit:** If your model is composed entirely of those three properties, you don't need a `Select` at all. You can simply do this:

```
var result = context.InvitationMails
             .Where(c => c.LinkStart == null && c.LinkEnd == null && c.Link == null);
```

Note in that case `result` will not be `IQueryable` of anonymous types, but of `InvitationMail` (considering your model's name is `InvitationMail`).